# The "--remote-storage-driver" option does not exist Magento 2.4.1

Tags: s3, magento24

I'm trying to set AWS S3 to storage magento media, but when I follow the tutorial in official Magento Page [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage.html) the bin/magento  setup:install --remote-storage-driver=`aws-s3` an error shows in terminal:

The `--remote-storage-driver` option does not exist

Some help?

Tks!

Comment: can you check that in your Magento installation there is a 'vendor/magento/module-aws-s3' module?

Comment: Have you already completed the configuration steps to use an AWS S3 bucket for remote storage? Looks like there's a few hoops to jump through: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html

Comment: @DianaBotean there´s no module-aws-s3 inside vendor/magento folder.

Comment: @kookaburra the problem is that there is no command --remote-storage-driver in bin/magento...when i execute ' bin/magento help setup:install ' do not list --remote-storage-driver as a command

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz Gotcha. I apologize, I must have read your question too quickly. I'm not sure module-aws-s3 is your problem since it may not have been introduced until 2.4.2 based on what I'm seeing in their Github (happy to be corrected if Diana Beaton has better information). Can I ask which Magento platform you're using? Magento Community and Commerce should each offer this CLI option, but Magento Cloud does not. I confirmed that in my cloud install and in the docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/reference/cli/magento-cloud.html

Comment: @kookaburra it i's Magento Community Edition 2.4.1 ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2.4.1 doesn't appear to offer this feature.

In my Magento 2.4.2 instance, this option is referenced in both the Magento_RemoteStorage and Magento_AwsS3 modules. These modules exist in the Github repository for [2.4.2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.2/app/code/Magento), but not in the repository for [2.4.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.1/app/code/Magento).

Also, in the [release notes for 2.4.2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html#aws-s3-support-enhancements), the Magento developers reference this feature (see below) with a link to your devdocs page. There's nothing comparable in the [release notes for 2.4.1](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-1.html). I'd say you can't find this option because it genuinely does not exist in 2.4.1.

Here's the relevant section:

> ## Magento Open Source 2.4.2 Release Notes
>
> ### AWS S3 support enhancements
>
>  Amazon Simple Storage Service (AWS S3) support has been enhanced to include support for:
>
> Object storage and future extensibility   [Storing media files](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage.html) on
> AWS S3

Comment: Yes, this is correct. 2 days ago a updated to Magento 2.4.2 and the feature is present. This answer the question, but now after configure the remote storage it's not working.

Comment: Happy to help answer this question... after it no longer matters, lol. I don't know much about the remote storage, so I hope you're able to get it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason is the module `Magento_AwsS3` has not been active yet, so magento can't find the aws-s3 driver. You can active it by this command:

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_AwsS3
```

But remember to install [aws-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/vi/cli/) in advance.